# Deal with empty arrays in WHERE clause

Tags: arrays, postgresql, python-2.7, psycopg2

I'm trying to execute queries using a function that receives a variable called `date`:

```
def initial_query(date):

# Some code verifying the correctness of the date

query = """   SELECT some_fields
                FROM tableA A
          INNER JOIN tableB B on A.transaction_id = B.transaccion_id
               WHERE A.action_id in (1,2,3)
                 AND A.test = false
                 AND (maf.client_id = ANY(%(clients)s::bigint[]) OR maf.merchant_code = ANY(%(merchants)s::varchar[]))
                 AND maf.country_iso = ANY(%(countries)s)
                 AND maf.date >= '{date}'
                 """

return query.format(date=date)
```

Inside `main()`, I'm using the `initial_query(date)` function in the following way:

```
cursor.execute(initial_query(starting_date), {'countries': countries, 'clients': client_ids,
                                                            'merchants': merchant_codes })
```

Where `cursor` is a psycopg2 cursor and the variables `countries, clients, merchants` can be empty lists in some cases (but not all). If I pass to the query an empty list, I'm going to obtain no results because any of the lines

```
 AND (maf.client_id = ANY(%(clients)s::bigint[]) OR maf.merchant_code = ANY(%(merchants)s::varchar[]))
 AND maf.pais_iso = ANY(%(countries)s)
```

always is going to return false. So I want to know if there is some way to use SQL code to modify the query inside initial_query, in order to avoid these lines always returning false because any of the lists passed to the cursor is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it adding a boolean variable to have two different queries for each case

```
def initial_query(date, is_segment=False):

# Some code verifying the correctness of the date
     if is_segment:
        query = """   SELECT some_fields
                        FROM tableA A
                  INNER JOIN tableB B on A.transaction_id = B.transaccion_id
                       WHERE A.action_id in (1,2,3)
                         AND A.test = false
                         AND (maf.client_id = ANY(%(clients)s::bigint[]) OR maf.merchant_code = ANY(%(merchants)s::varchar[]))
                         AND maf.date >= '{date}'
                 """
    else:
        query = """   SELECT some_fields
                        FROM tableA A
                  INNER JOIN tableB B on A.transaction_id = B.transaccion_id
                       WHERE A.action_id in (1,2,3)
                         AND A.test = false
                         AND maf.country_iso = ANY(%(countries)s)
                         AND maf.date >= '{date}'
                 """
    return query.format(date=date)
```